# Adding "Site Page" Content type in Pages library inside SharePoint Online modern Site does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, pages

I am tried to enable modern page in "Pages" library by adding the "Site Page" content type inside "Pages" Library in modern SharePoint online site.
After adding the content type , while creating the modern page by selecting the "Site Page" content type does not work.

Kindly help in this case.

Thanks,
Kailash

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to Pages library settings -> Advanced settings -> Set List experience as New experience

2.In the modern experience library, when you click New -> site page, you will create a new modern page.